# Help regarding ugrading iis on windows xp

Tags: iis

i am right now on windows xp and iis v5.1,  Can i upgrade this to IISv6.0 on windows xp, is it supported. IF so where should i download the installation file for it.

Answer (score 5):

Look [here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1095675.aspx) for a few suggestions. By default it isn't possible, but since the files for IIS 6 are inside Service Pack 3 (for Windows Server 2003) you can extract them (see the link for instructions how to do that).

You could also look at [IIS Express](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/).